# Apply an interface in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, refactoring

I am creating a project with `Node JS` and `Typescript`, I have a class and an interface where I type all the data. What I need to know is how to apply it to the classroom.

This is my `interface`:

```
export interface IController {
    url: string,
    api: string
}
```

This is my `class` where I want to apply it:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { constUtils } from '../utils/const.utils';
import { IController } from '../utils/model.utils';
import { utilsController } from '../utils/index.utils';

class IndexController {

    public async index(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<IController> {

        try {
            let api = req.query.api;
            let constUt = new constUtils();
            let url = constUt.conf.API_MOCS[`${api}`].url;
            await utilsController.utilsCsvConverter(api, url);         
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
export const indexController = new IndexController();
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Where exactly do you want to apply the interface? Directly to the `IndexController` class or as something that is returned by the `index()` function?

Comment: @Phoenix1355 Directly in the ``index()`` for data typing

Comment: Import the `csvModel` interface in the file containing `IndexController`, then give the `index()` method a return type - assuming that you're trying to return a `csvModel` from the method: `public async index(req: Request, res: Response): csvModel { /* ... */ }`

Comment: @j1mbl3s Updated the question. Can I return a ``res.json`` message for example with the interface data? or how should I return and what value to solve the following problem ?: ``A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that the local variables `url` and `api` should be returned in a `Promise` resolving to an object specified the by `IController` interface:

```js
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { constUtils } from '../utils/const.utils';
import { IController } from '../utils/model.utils';
import { utilsController } from '../utils/index.utils';

class IndexController {
    public async index(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<IController> {

        try {
            let api = req.query.api;
            let constUt = new constUtils();
            let url = constUt.conf.API_MOCS[`${api}`].url;
            await utilsController.utilsCsvConverter(api, url);
            return {url, api};         
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
export const indexController = new IndexController();
```

Comment: I am using the interface for data typing, I am starting with Typescript and what I want is to refactor the project as much as possible. In this case the data is not typed and ``Promise <IController>`` shows the following error: ``A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value``

Comment: I'm not sure what the method index is supposed to do, but it does not seem to return anything and actually also has no async function call, so you could just define it without `async` and give it a return type of `void`.

Comment: What I want to know is the best way to initialize variables in Typescript and type them, from what I've read is using interfaces but I don't know how to apply them.

Comment: Just before you mentioned that you get an error with the return type and I answered on how to deal with this error. Without understanding what variables you want to initialise and type, it is hard to help. My guess was based on the names of your variables and it looks to me, as if you are referring to the `url` and `api`. I still donÄt know what you might want to use the interface for? If you just want to initialise a variable this can be done implicitly `let url = '';` or explicitly `let url: string = '';`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html

Comment: It is worth the initialization before, I will study better the use of Interfaces. On the other hand, how can I return the Promise to make it return the variables and show them as json, using res.json but applying it to the promise is it possible? If not, how is a Promise returned?

Comment: I gave it another try with your interface and added other example.

Comment: I'm still not sure what Promise you want to return. There is no return from your function and  I see noting returning a function in your example. Actually the only function call is the `constUtils()` constructor and there is no other function call. If you show me where the Promise is or what you want to return , I might be able t help you.

Comment: I want to have the following variables ``let api: string``, and ``let url: string``. I would think that the best way to initialize and use them is an interface, but I don't know if it is better to use it or not. How could I best do this then?

Comment: If you want to initialise them independently, just create each one individually (let api = ''; let url = '';). If you want to use them as on object one once, just create an object `const data = {api: '', url: ''}`. If you want to use the object multiple times, use an `interface`, `type` or `class`.

Comment: Okay, so I need to create an ``interface`` because those variables I want to use soon in another class. I update the question with the class now

Comment: Yes, if you want to reuse a data structure that contains those two variables, I would create an `interface` or `type` that btw are pretty much the same.

Comment: Okay, now I have the code as in the question but I did not understand very well how to solve the error for this code: ``A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value``.

Comment: 1) you are no longer using the `csvModel` interface. 2) I've tried to help you with the Promise but you never answered my questions: I'm still not sure what Promise you want to return. There is no return from your function and I see noting returning a function in your example. Actually the only function call is the constUtils() constructor and there is no other function call. If you show me where the Promise is or what you want to return , I might be able t help you.

Comment: Sorry to change the name and I didn't realize I changed it in the question. The only thing I have is the interface and the class where I want to use it, I have used the promise because you have told me so but the only thing I have is the interface and the class.

Comment: If you look at your original example it already contained an async function and a Promise as return value and I never suggested using a Promise but rather asked multiple times what the Promise is supposed to do! Now that you finally explained that you want to return an object defined by the `IController interface` and no Promise is involved, I will update my original answer.

Comment: I now updated my original answer and basically you only missed to return the Promise. Does my answer now solve your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want use or apply interface to the class you should have to **`implement`** it within the applied class. Below code might give you clear idea.

```
class IndexController implements csvModel {
    url: string;
    api: string;

    public async index(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<IController> {

        try {
            this.api = req.query.api;
            let constUt = new constUtils();
            this.url = constUt.conf.API_MOCS[`${api}`].url;           
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
export const indexController = new IndexController();
```

Comment: This is the same as before, it gives me a failure in Promise <IController>: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value

Comment: You must return something from both try and catch block as its not a void function, your return type is a `Promise<IController>` either remove this `Promise<IController>` or `return {}` empty object

Comment: What is the reason for implementing IndexController as a csvModel?

Comment: It will typecast the value of `api` and `url` with the interface. Also could be helpful in in scenarios: `export const csvModel = new IndexController(); csvModel.api`

Comment: Sorry, but I still do not understand if it is better to use Interfaces or not in this case and how to initialize them to use them later

Comment: @Bhaginath The original question was very ambiguous but I would find it quite unusual if a class implements an interface that just contains some state. It took me a while, but it now seems as if the intention of this code was to return an object that implements the given interface.

Comment: @doberkofler That's obvious, but I would think adding an interface would give you extra flexibility which will make sure that the implemented class should return or implement the contract specified in an interface.

Comment: @Bhaginath What exactly was obvious for you? Your example does actually not return the interface, but where do you see added flexibility by defining a class that implements an interface containing two properties?

Comment: @doberkofler I meant it depends on the situation and the scenarios weather you would like to use it. this [link](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/the-role-of-interfaces-in-typescript) might clear your views on interfaces and regarding the  answer I just implemented the interface, for return either we need to make it complete void function or just return null will work and once you initialized you can access the value.

Comment: @Bhaginath I understand that there are reasons for having a class that implements an interface, but I was wondering why you suggested this pattern here or where you see the additional flexibility.

Comment: @doberkofler Well as per the question I thought sirtz needs it with interface, so I gave the answer straightway here, that's It!